# Dependent Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have to calculate a closed formula for all possible permutation in the next problem.
   Assume we have a line graph with $n$ nodes. Each node may be in one of two possible states, $v_i\in {a,b}$ and each edge may be in one of two possible states according to the following function: \begin{align}\label{eq:edgePotential}
   \psi(v_{i},v_{j})=\begin{cases}
p & ,v_{i}=v_{j}\\
q& ,v_{i}\neq v_{j}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Therefore weight  of edge dependents the values of its nodes.
For example, assume we have a line graph with three nodes:
[Line graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLeKE.png)

[image]
and all possible permutations of this graph are:
[All permutations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHNI1.png)

[image]

Comment: The node dependent part of the formula is easy, $(a+b)^n$. The $p$ and $q$ part will be formula will in general be difficult to calculate and will be closely related to solving the Ising model for the given graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you about the node parts, it is a binomial function. Can u please explain what do you mean "to solving Ising model"?

Comment: See the second formula in the definition section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Definitions. You are essentially wanting to evaluate the Energy function for a two state model where the energy function is given by a sum on the parity of the edges.